# How can I repeat a simulation multiple times?

Tags: r

I'm really new to Rstudio so I hope someone can help me.
So I have this code:

```
x = 1:5
alpha = 1
beta = 1.5
betaD = 0.1
s = 1
sa = 0.2
sb = 0.2
N = 10

grp = factor(rep(c("Control", "Treatment"), c(N,N)))

for(i in 1:(2*N)) {
  ai = rnorm(1, 0, sa)
  bi = rnorm(1, 0, sb)
  intercept = alpha+ai
  slope = beta + bi + ifelse(grp[i]=="Treatment", betaD, 0.0)

  y = intercept+ slope*x + rnorm(length(x), 0, s)

  tmp = data.frame(subject=i, x=x, y=y, a=ai, b=bi, group=grp[i])
  if(i==1) dataset = tmp
  else dataset = rbind(dataset, tmp)
}

require(lme4)

fitAll= lmList(y~x|subject, data=dataset)
slopes = coef(fitAll)$x
boxplot(slopes~grp)
t.test(slopes~grp, var.equal=TRUE)

fit0 = lmer(y~ x +(x|subject), data=dataset, REML=FALSE)
fit1 = lmer(y~ group*x +(x|subject), data=dataset, REML=FALSE)
anova(fit0, fit1)
```

When I run this, it generates this:

```
Two Sample t-test

data:  slopes by grp
t = -2.2495, df = 18, p-value = 0.03723
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.66690111 -0.02277686
sample estimates:
  mean in group Control mean in group Treatment 
               1.362975                1.707814
```

and this:

```
Data: dataset
Models:
fit0: y ~ x + (x | subject)
fit1: y ~ group * x + (x | subject)
     Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
fit0  6 326.65 342.28 -157.32   314.65                           
fit1  8 324.34 345.18 -154.17   308.34 6.3072      2     0.0427 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Basically what I want to do is put a repeat in the code so that when I click run, it will generate this however many times I specify. Then I want it to sort the p-value it generates into two groups, one group where the p-value is above 0.05 and another where it is below 0.05

As I said I'm really new to this so if someone could explain it to me simply, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

To run code several times, use `replicate`. Something like

```
replicate(
  100,
  {
     # Your code that creates the random dataset and runs ANOVA
  }
)
```

Answer (score 6):

I took the p-value from `t.test` for simplicity, it might be not the p-value that you mean. However, it will suit for demonstration purposes.

Simply wrap your code in a function and use `replicate` as many times as you desire:

```
do_once <- function()
{
  x = 1:5
  alpha = 1
  beta = 1.5
  betaD = 0.1
  s = 1
  sa = 0.2
  sb = 0.2
  N = 10

  grp = factor(rep(c("Control", "Treatment"), c(N,N)))

  for(i in 1:(2*N)) {
    ai = rnorm(1, 0, sa)
    bi = rnorm(1, 0, sb)
    intercept = alpha+ai
    slope = beta + bi + ifelse(grp[i]=="Treatment", betaD, 0.0)

    y = intercept+ slope*x + rnorm(length(x), 0, s)

    tmp = data.frame(subject=i, x=x, y=y, a=ai, b=bi, group=grp[i])
    if(i==1) dataset = tmp
    else dataset = rbind(dataset, tmp)
  }

  require(lme4)

  fitAll= lmList(y~x|subject, data=dataset)
  slopes = coef(fitAll)$x
  boxplot(slopes~grp)
  t.test(slopes~grp, var.equal=TRUE)$p.value  
}
p_vals <- replicate(10, do_once())
```

To get p-values lower than 0.05, simply

```
p_vals[p_vals < 0.05]
```

And yes, this has nothing to do with Rstudio, the R code will work in any IDE and in plain R console.

Comment: Ok that makes some sense. My problem now when I actually run the code, it comes up with an error that says "Error in integer(n) : invalid 'length' argument". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, incorrect order of parameters. Try again now.

Comment: That seems to have worked. It doesn't exactly generate it like the results I've got above though. And when it runs the last line (p_vals[p_vals < 0.05]) I get another error message that says "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'".

Comment: It depends on the object that is returned from `do_once`. If that's a single value (like in the code above), then the result is a vector `p_vals`. If not, then the object returned by `replicate` is a list. You can see the type of the object by running e.g. `str(p_vals)`.

Comment: Oh wait hang on I figured out the problem. On your code on the third last line you wrote $p.value. I didn't include that bit. It worked now. Can I use the same method to run the t.test and the ANOVA at the same time?

Comment: Yes, of course, just assign the p-value to a temporary variable, run ANOVA and then return that variable.